Need to make these graphs filterable by both slicers *SAMPLE PBIX ATTACHED*
I'm working on a project where I need to show trennding revenue for active clients by quarter. For example, if Q1 2022 had 2000 active clients and I selected that quarter in my slicer, I want a revenue trending graph that shows revenue for those 2000 clients between 2020-2024, regardless of whether they deconverted later
I'm attempting to do this using a disconnected date table, and I can get it to work, but when it does, another slicer in my report breaks and no longer functions.
I've attached a sample PBIX that contains relevant data. In that pbix, both slicers should work to filter the graph, but I can only get one to work at a time. Any help on this would be much appreciated.
https://upload.disroot.org/r/JBjAgytN#dDNJTdfJ+BUTtcwGn46l0iSRVXZTk+jMfdFwoKCm67s=
I've tried messing with both the "cohorts" measure and the various relationships I'm using, but nothing has had any effect. I do believe the primary issue is with either the relationships or the cohorts measure.
